# Neo4j Cypher Query multiple relationship from same node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I Have a node called `Member` it has **Relationships** to `Clubs` and `Shops`  I want to create a query so that I can return `Member` with `Clubs` and `Shops`

```
MATCH (m: Member { username: $memberUsername ,
                  password: $password})<- [r: MEMBER_BELONGS_TO_CLUBS] - (c: Club)
RETURN m, c, r
```

in the example I get `Member` and `Clubs` but I want to get member `Clubs` and member `Shops`

Comment: So what is Shop and why it is not included in your query?

Answer (score 1):

If your node `M` is connected like this `S -> M <- C` (M is `Member`, S is `Shop`, and C is `Club`), then you can use query similar like example in **4.2 Multiple Relationships** in [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/):

```
MATCH (s: Shop) - [rs: MEMBER_BELONGS_TO_SHOPS] ->
      (m: Member { username: $memberUsername ,
                   password: $password}) <- [r: MEMBER_BELONGS_TO_CLUBS] - (c: Club)
RETURN m, c, r, s, rs
```

Also you can use syntax like in this [example](https://community.neo4j.com/t/multiple-match-queries/16696) with multiple `MATCH`:

```
MATCH (m: Member { username: $memberUsername ,
                  password: $password})
MATCH (s: Shop) - [rs: MEMBER_BELONGS_TO_SHOPS] -> (m)
MATCH (m) <- [r: MEMBER_BELONGS_TO_CLUBS] - (c: Club)
RETURN m, c, r, s, rs
```

And both queries returns something only if `M` is connected with both `S` and `C`. If you
don't want that restrictions you can use `OPTIONAL MATCH` [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/).